# How to set more lines to scroll backwards, in text mode?

Tags: linux, terminal, text-mode

I want to scroll back 10000+ lines in text mode linux terminal. As there is an unlimit option in `gnome-terminal`, so I guess if this is also possible in text mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can increase the scrollback buffer size by changing the kernel configuration, recompile and re-install your new kernel. IN menuconfig

Device Drivers -> Graphics Support -> Console Display driver support

```
config VGACON_SOFT_SCROLLBACK_SIZE                                                                                                  
       int "Scrollback Buffer Size (in KB)"                                                                                         
       depends on VGACON_SOFT_SCROLLBACK                                                                                            
       range 1 1024                                                                                                                 
       default "64"                                                                                                                 
       help                                                                                                                         
         Enter the amount of System RAM to allocate for the scrollback                                                              
         buffer.  Each 64KB will give you approximately 16 80x25                                                                    
         screenfuls of scrollback buffer
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe it cannot be done in text mode:
http://www.educ.umu.se/~bjorn/linux/linux-faq/Linux-FAQ-7.html

> You can't increase the amount of
>   scrollback, because it is implemented
>   using the video memory to store the
>   scrollback text. You may be able to
>   get more scrollback in each virtual
>   console by reducing the total number
>   of VC's. See linux/tty.h.