# Enabling mouse scrolling in OS X terminal man pages

Tags: macos, terminal.app, scrolling, manpages

I have been trying to find a way for the OS X Terminal to accept the mouse input to scroll in the man pages.

I have installed SIMBL and [MouseTerm](https://bitheap.org/mouseterm/) but this does not enable scrolling in the man pages. 
Any sugestions?

Answer (score 1):

The amount of the man page that you can see at one time is determined by the buffer size. Here is how to [change it](https://superuser.com/questions/188993/increase-linux-terminal-scrollback-buffer-size).

After much trial and error, I have enabled scrolling in vim, but not for man pages.

Append to your ~/.vimrc

```
set mouse=a
set ttymouse=xterm2
```

The [following blog](http://usevim.com/2012/05/16/mouse/) shows how to enable scrolling in vim using iTerm2. It unfortunately does not work on man pages.

---

**As a work around, I would suggest:**

[*NIXmanual](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/18148/*nix-manual) - A widget you enable on your Mac that cointains the man pages

[linuxmanpages.com](http://www.linuxmanpages.com) - A website will all linux man pages

Use the standard vim keys 'hjkl' or <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Page Up</kbd> and<kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Page Down</kbd>

---

**Additional Resources**

[Arch linux forum discussion 1](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=52694)
[Arch linux forum discussion 2](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=445272)

Comment: In addition to the standard vim navigation, you can use `d` to scroll down half a page and `u` to scroll up half a page in man pages (and in less). You can also open man pages in vim with `vim <(man foo)`; you could put that into a function in your `.bashrc`, something like: `myman() { vim <(man "$1"); }`, and then use it like `myman foo`. I'm aware that OSX uses bash version 3.x, so I don't know if process substitution works there, but if it does then that could be a workaround for getting the mouse in manpages.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late to the party  (*as usual*) but I came across this question today, and only saw one answer that had some external links in it.

So the solution I came up with was to use one of my favorite text editors [nvim](https://neovim.io/) to handle opening of man pages within a terminal session.

Now, you could go about by setting the `$PAGER` environment variable or the `$MANPAGER` variable to vim for shell session and I suppose that would work.

But however I decided to write a custom function for my shell, which happens to be [fish-shell](http://fishshell.com/), however I'm sure both BASH and ZSH both support functions as well.

The reason I chose to go the function route was that I didn't really want to always use nvim as my `PAGER` for my own obvious reasons.  However, if I could just run a command such as `vman` to open a man page within nvim that'd be awesome, thus leaving the `$PAGER`, `$MANPAGER` environment variables intact along with the `man` command as well.

So I created a function that looks like the below, added some comments so I'd have understanding of what all the flags are doing, so that way I wouldn't have to  ...open the man page

```
function vman --description 'use vim / nvim to read man pages'

  # col `-b` flag = don't output any backspaces
  # col `-p` flag = force uknown control sequences
  # ===
  # iconv `-c` flag = characters that can't be converter are
  # ...silently discarded
  # ===
  # nvim `-c` flag = run argument / command after executing nvim
  # nvim `-R` flag = open "file" in read-only mode
  # ===
  man $argv | col -bp | iconv -c | nvim -c 'set ft=man nomod nolist' -;
end
```

Obviously your going to need mouse support enabled in vim / nvim which can be done by adding the below line to the respected editors configuration file.

```
set mouse=a
```